# Как присвоить каждой ссылке, полученной с JSOUP, свою переменную?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Есть код для получения ссылок со страницы, спарсенной при помощи JSOUP:

```
cntContent.setClickable(true);
cntContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

То есть после выполнения этого кода все ссылки, которые есть в спарсенном участке html, становятся активными, и по ним можно кликнуть и перейти на страницы сайта.

Я хотел бы каждой такой ссылке присвоить переменную (например, var1, var2, var3 и т.д.) и задать условие через onClickListener.

Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно такое сделать через `ClickableSpan`. Проблема только в том, что вам самим придется находить ссылки в тексте и соответственно присваивать нужным переменным эти ссылки. Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418663/7104538)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать.